# Cannot access fixedRateTimer in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project. And I'm trying to use a timer and countdown timer but I cannot access `kotlin.concurrent.fixedRateTimer` or `import kotlin.concurrent.timer` in `commonMain` module.

[image]

However the `kotlin.concurrent` is available:
[image]

This is root `build.gradle` :

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
}

// ...

kotlin {
    //...
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.10")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9")
                //...
            }
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

I wonder if it's even possible to use these methods there. If not, how can I write a timer and countdown timer in `commonMain` module?

I have tried to use `Coroutines` to achieve the same functionality but failed because they are not precise:

```
    fun doAfter(delay: Long, action: () -> (Unit)) = launch {
        delay(delay)
        action.invoke()
    }

    fun countdown(time: Long, tick: Long, onTick: () -> (Unit), onFinish: () -> (Unit)) = launch {
        val ticks = (time / tick).toInt()
        repeat(ticks) {
            onTick()
            delay(tick)
        }
        onFinish()
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said by Qaz, the function you are trying to use in common code is [JVM only](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/fixed-rate-timer.html).

Usually in KMP, when you still don't have a common functionality already built in by the framework you could follow different approaches:

1. Use someone else library (e.g. [moko-time](https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-time)) - Best place for searching libraries is [here](https://libs.kmp.icerock.dev/).
2. Use the native framworks classes by the [`expect`/`actual`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/mpp-connect-to-apis.html) mechanism

Just to give you and example of what could be done (not sure if that is right for you or could fit your needs. It's just to put you in the right direction and above all what I've wrote could not be production ready at all [-;)

**`commonMain:Timer.kt`**

```kotlin
expect class KMMTimer(
    name: String? = null,
    interval: Long,
    delay: Long,
    action: () -> Unit
) {
    val name: String?
    val interval: Long
    val delay: Long

    fun start()
    fun cancel()
    fun isRunning(): Boolean
}
```

**`androidMain:Timer.kt`**

```kotlin
import java.util.*
import kotlin.concurrent.fixedRateTimer

actual class KMMTimer actual constructor(
    actual val name: String?,
    actual val interval: Long,
    actual val delay: Long,
    action: () -> Unit
) {
    private var timer: Timer? = null
    private val action = action

    actual fun start() {
        if (!isRunning()) {
            timer = fixedRateTimer(
                name = name,
                initialDelay = delay,
                period = interval
            ) {
                action()
            }
        }
    }

    actual fun cancel() {
        timer?.cancel()
        timer = null
    }

    actual fun isRunning(): Boolean {
        return timer != null
    }
}
```

**`iosMain:Timer.kt`**

```kotlin
import platform.Foundation.NSDate
import platform.Foundation.NSRunLoop
import platform.Foundation.NSRunLoopCommonModes
import platform.Foundation.NSTimer

actual class KMMTimer actual constructor(
    actual val name: String?,
    actual val interval: Long,
    actual val delay: Long,
    action: () -> Unit
) {
    private var timer: NSTimer? = null
    private var action = action

    actual fun start() {
        if (!isRunning()) {
            timer = NSTimer(
                fireDate = NSDate(
                    NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate + (delay.toDouble() / 1000)
                ),
                interval = (interval.toDouble() / 1000),
                repeats = true,
                block = {
                    action()
                }
            )
            timer?.let {
                NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(it, NSRunLoopCommonModes)
            }
        }
    }

    actual fun cancel() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = null
    }

    actual fun isRunning(): Boolean {
        return timer != null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function you are trying to use is JVM only. See
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/fixed-rate-timer.html

Comment: How can I achieve the same functionality there?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `@shadowsheep's` answer is great. But for me there is one caveat with ios *NSTimer block action* that was never fired. The problem was in `NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop`. The solution is:

```
        timer?.let {
            NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop.addTimer(it, NSRunLoopCommonModes)
        }
```